# #Solace - Implementing DR for solace Java JMS publisher

Tags: solace

I have an existing application which was running on solace jar v7.1.2 execute in pub/sub mode. Now we have upgraded to v10.1.1 and as part of implementing DR setup(Disaster Recovery), I have added one more host in the configuration with comma separated.
The application could connect to the primary host successfully, but during the switch-over, (ie from primary to DR) the application had failed to connect and i have received the below error. It connects to DR host if I restart my application.

```
com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 400: Unknown Flow Name [Subcode:55]
        at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.PubFlowManager.doPubAssuredCtrl(PubFlowManager.java:266)
        at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.PubFlowManager.notifyReconnected(PubFlowManager.java:452)
        at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel$ClientChannelReconnect.call(TcpClientChannel.java:2097)
        ... 5 more
|EAI-000376|||ERROR|    |EAI-000376 JMS Exception occurred, Description: `Error sending message - unknown flow name ((JCSMPTransportException)
```

Need help to understand if we need to have some configuration to do the reconnect to the DR host for a smooth switch over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solace JMS API versions earlier than 7.1.2.226, any sessions on which the clients have published Guaranteed messages will be destroyed after a DR switch‑over. To indicate the disconnect and loss of publisher flow the JMS API will generate this exception. Upon receiving these exceptions, the client application should create a new session. After a new session is established, the client application can republish any Guaranteed messages that had been sent but not acked on the previous session, as these message might not have been persisted and replicated.

However, this behavior was improved in version 7.1.2.226 and later so that the API handles this transparently. It is no longer required to implement code to catch this exception. Can you please verify that the application is not using an API earlier 7.1.2.226? This can be done by enabling debug-level logs.

Comment: Thank you Alexandra for your response.

Comment: We were using the jar version 7.1.0.207 earlier and for this testing we have upgraded to 10.1.1. But we got the exception as I quoted in my question. So does that mean the application is still referring to older one ? Also what's the time that require to do the connection switch-over automatically if the new API handles it by default?

Comment: @user9391262 Yes, it is possible that it is still referring to the old jar. A DR switch-over still needs to be manually performed on the router. When the switch-over is done, the application will automatically reconnect.

Comment: Thank You. Will cross-check this.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexandra pointed out, when using guaranteed messaging, as of version 7.1.2 the Solace JMS API guarantees delivery even in the case of failover. It is normal to receive INFO-level log messages that say "`Error Response (400) - Unknown Flow Name`", this does not indicate a problem, but exceptions (with stack traces) **are** a problem and indicate that delivery is not guaranteed.

Background: if the connection between the client and the broker (on the Solace server) is terminated unexpectedly, the broker maintains the flow state — but only for three minutes. The state is also copied to the HA mate broker to support failover (but not to the replication mate). If the client reconnects within three minutes, it can resume where it left off. If it reconnects after three minutes, the server will respond with the following (which will be echoed to the logs):

```
2019-01-04 10:00:59,999 INFO  [com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.PubFlowManager] (Context_2_Thread_reconnect_service) Error Response (400) - Unknown Flow Name
2019-01-04 10:00:59,999 INFO  [com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.PubADManager] (Context_2_Thread_reconnect_service) Unknown Publisher Flow (flowId=36) recovered: 1 messages renumbered and resent (lastMessageIdSent =0)
```

That's okay: the client JMS library will automatically resend whatever messages are necessary, so guaranteed messaging is still guaranteed.

Also, just to confirm, the jar name indicates the version, so `sol-jms-10.1.1.jar` uses version 10.1.1.